# ♥ Summer clean up ♥

Tags: discussion, cleanup

A user just [pointed me](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155304/image-maps-lightbox-plugin?noredirect=1#comment223881_155304) at our sidebar. It shows *related* questions and she wrote the following, complaining why her *plugin recommendation*-question was closed as off topic.

> ok, I dont want to sound like a b**** but I've seen lots and lots of questions answered when people ask for tools, libraries and off site resources. I am even looking at some here at the related sidebar....

She is right with one thing: We made those things off topic a long time ago. What we haven't managed (because of the lack of wo|menpower) is closing all of them. But she also pointed me at another interesting thing. Namely it's using the "related questions" sidebar to hunt down those questions. It's really an *excellent* and *highly accurate* tool for this task, as the SE/SO network developers have spent quite some time and brain power developing it.

### Give *WordPress Developers SE* some ♥

Just search up *one or two* plugin recommendation questions. Search queries like

- [tool](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=tool) 1,494 results
- [plugin+for](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=plugin%2Bfor) 27,328 results

will work. And then the "related" sidebar widget already kicks in, delivering you targets.

**Task:** Flag and downvote (or if you got the capability: close vote) **5 questions**. It will probably just take you **30 seconds**, but you will do a big job for this site - and also for the relevance of your search results.

*Hint: Down voting questions doesn't cost you reputation.*

Comment: Will definetly help with those. I'm a very active close voter, but my problem is, I think 24 close votes is somedays just too little. Are there a way that these 24 limit will someday be increased :-). Like now, I'm out of votes, and 95% + of the questions I voted on was put on hold, so I'm not wasting my votes.

Comment: @PieterGoosen The close voting queue is sky rocketing at the moment. :)

Comment: O hell, "so I'm not wasting my votes" should have been "so I have not wasted my votes" sorry about that. Will vote as soon as I get new votes in a couple of hours. This 24 vote limit stinks

Comment: I second @PieterGoosen: I've never had problems with review and/or vote limits. But when engaging in this task, they are indeed annoying. I'd much rather do this for an hour or two straight than 10 minutes every day...

Comment: What happens to Closed Questions and On Hold Questions? Do they both eventually get deleted or are they just permalocked?

Comment: Turns out to extend into fall, eh?!

Comment: @JohannesPille maybe even into winter. :)

Answer (score 9):

I like the idea of @kaiser, but it is a bit biased (North-sided). As there are a couple of guys in the southern hemisphere, which are currently wrapped in a state of something called winter, it seems like were are excluded here. We are still a few months away from summer.

So I would like to invite the guys from the southern hemisphere to participate in the

**♥ Winter clean up ♥**

program

The same concept would apply as the "♥ Summer clean up ♥", except it would be called **♥ Winter clean up ♥** for our guys.

And here is my hint

*To hell with reputation, if an answer is really bad, also downvote it. It just costs one reputation, but it will safe someone a ton of time reading a poor quality answer*

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph!!!