# Which are wordpress related questions and which are not?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging, off-topic

I have found some questions was held which are really Wordpress related. I found some questions are put on hold due to plugins, API, etc.... I got several tags that are available in wordpress.stackexchange.com and some people tags with them.

**My Questions is:**

> 1) If tag is available and some questions on that tag then why its put hold?

"Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes."

Third party plugins like (pods-framework,plugin-wp-seo-yoast etc)

> 2) I found some third party related tags and questions are approved and some are rejected. Is there any reason to do that?

Actually, I am just trying to understand. I don't want bad contribution of StackExchange site.

Comment: AFAIK, these were on-topic at some point. But then because of all the unwanted fringe topics and spams the community decided against them. But cleaning up is not that easy. You'll find [a related discussion here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3917/why-keep-plugin-specific-tags-when-all-plugin-specific-questions-are-considered)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not about "related", it is about "specific". Easy example is JS/CSS questions which can be asked about any other platform.

More complex is theme/plugins questions. If it is possible to give a generic wordpress answer it is cool, but if the question is specific to that theme or plugin than it is not specific to wordpress, but specific to the theme/plugin. Or you can look at it the other way around, plugin and theme question should raise generic wordpress issues to be "valid" questions.

Tags are mostly user generated and there is not too much smart control over them. They are means for people that would like to follow specific topics or search by it, no more than that. The fact that a question with a specific tag was "approved" do not carry any weight for other questions with that tag.

Comment: Tags also allow people to **ignore** a topic. `woocommerce` is a common example.

Comment: I actually didn't know about this, thanks. However when I add a tag to my ignore list, the questions are just grayed out, not hidden. Is that a normal behavior or is there a way to hide them completely? @toscho

Comment: @JackJohansson They are hidden in _some_ views, as far as I remember. As a mod, I don't have the luxury to ignore anything, so I can't help with personal experience. :)

Comment: Actually just found out that you can hide them totally in the user preference, but as you mentioned, a mod should not try this at home :P @toscho